Convert date column with DDMMMYYYY strings into YYYYMMDD string in Pandas
Convert a date column loaded as strings into a pandas dataframe, in the format DDMMMYYYY (i.e. %d%b%Y) to the desired format of YYYYMMDD (i.e. %Y%m%d).
Example: Convert 31Oct2023 to 20231031.
   GivenInput ExpectedDates
0   31Jan2023      20230131
1   28Feb2023      20230228
2   31Mar2023      20230331
3   30Apr2023      20230430
4   31May2023      20230531
5   30Jun2023      20230630
6   31Jul2023      20230731
7   31Aug2023      20230831
8   30Sep2023      20230930
9   31Oct2023      20231031
10  30Nov2023      20231130
11  31Dec2023      20231231
12  31Jan2024      20240131
13  29Feb2024      20240229
14  31Mar2024      20240331
15  30Apr2024      20240430
16  31May2024      20240531

Snippet to load the sample data:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """
GivenInput
31Jan2023
28Feb2023
31Mar2023
30Apr2023
31May2023
30Jun2023
31Jul2023
31Aug2023
30Sep2023
31Oct2023
30Nov2023
31Dec2023
31Jan2024
29Feb2024
31Mar2024
30Apr2024
31May2024
"""
s = s.strip()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
print(df)


Strategy: raw date string --> datetime --> string format as '%Y%m%d'
Convert the string values of the date into type 'datetime64[ns]'. This makes pandas recognize the string date-values as datetime values. The .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d') further converts these datetime values into strings in the expected format, %Y%m%d.

NOTE: The dataframe df was created with the code snippet in section Dummy Data.

df["ExpectedDates"] = df["GivenInput"].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print(df)

Output:
   GivenInput ExpectedDates
0   31Jan2023      20230131
1   28Feb2023      20230228
2   31Mar2023      20230331
3   30Apr2023      20230430
4   31May2023      20230531
5   30Jun2023      20230630
6   31Jul2023      20230731
7   31Aug2023      20230831
8   30Sep2023      20230930
9   31Oct2023      20231031
10  30Nov2023      20231130
11  31Dec2023      20231231
12  31Jan2024      20240131
13  29Feb2024      20240229
14  31Mar2024      20240331
15  30Apr2024      20240430
16  31May2024      20240531

Notes for the Inquisitive
The following conversion loads the data as datetime; however, the pandas display show the datetime values as follows.

31Oct2023 --> 2023-10-31

df["DateTimeAsIs"] = df["GivenInput"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(df)

Output:
   GivenInput  ExpectedDates DateTimeAsIs
0   31Jan2023       20230131   2023-01-31
1   28Feb2023       20230228   2023-02-28
2   31Mar2023       20230331   2023-03-31
3   30Apr2023       20230430   2023-04-30
4   31May2023       20230531   2023-05-31
5   30Jun2023       20230630   2023-06-30
6   31Jul2023       20230731   2023-07-31
7   31Aug2023       20230831   2023-08-31
8   30Sep2023       20230930   2023-09-30
9   31Oct2023       20231031   2023-10-31
10  30Nov2023       20231130   2023-11-30
11  31Dec2023       20231231   2023-12-31
12  31Jan2024       20240131   2024-01-31
13  29Feb2024       20240229   2024-02-29
14  31Mar2024       20240331   2024-03-31
15  30Apr2024       20240430   2024-04-30
16  31May2024       20240531   2024-05-31

Thorough Comparison of Alternate Methods
# Method-A
df["DateTimeAsIs_A"] = df["GivenInput"].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df["ExpectedOutput_A"] = df["GivenInput"].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
# Method-B
df["DateTimeAsIs_B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["GivenInput"], format='%d%b%Y')
df["ExpectedOutput_B"] = pd.to_datetime(df["GivenInput"], format='%d%b%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print(df)

Output:
   GivenInput DateTimeAsIs_A ExpectedOutput_A DateTimeAsIs_B ExpectedOutput_B
0   31Jan2023     2023-01-31         20230131     2023-01-31         20230131
1   28Feb2023     2023-02-28         20230228     2023-02-28         20230228
2   31Mar2023     2023-03-31         20230331     2023-03-31         20230331
3   30Apr2023     2023-04-30         20230430     2023-04-30         20230430
4   31May2023     2023-05-31         20230531     2023-05-31         20230531
5   30Jun2023     2023-06-30         20230630     2023-06-30         20230630
6   31Jul2023     2023-07-31         20230731     2023-07-31         20230731
7   31Aug2023     2023-08-31         20230831     2023-08-31         20230831
8   30Sep2023     2023-09-30         20230930     2023-09-30         20230930
9   31Oct2023     2023-10-31         20231031     2023-10-31         20231031
10  30Nov2023     2023-11-30         20231130     2023-11-30         20231130
11  31Dec2023     2023-12-31         20231231     2023-12-31         20231231
12  31Jan2024     2024-01-31         20240131     2024-01-31         20240131
13  29Feb2024     2024-02-29         20240229     2024-02-29         20240229
14  31Mar2024     2024-03-31         20240331     2024-03-31         20240331
15  30Apr2024     2024-04-30         20240430     2024-04-30         20240430
16  31May2024     2024-05-31         20240531     2024-05-31         20240531

Validate:
all(df['ExpectedOutput_A'] == df['ExpectedOutput_B']) # output: True

Refer to this SO question for method-B.
